# concatenar arquivos csv python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, ipython-notebook

3 listas que formam o diretório e o nome do arquivo, quero concatenar os arquivos "listas_tipos_anos.csv" (em torno de 44 arquivos) em "listas_tipos_all.csv" (gerar 4 arquivos), onde o "all" é toda a junção dos arquivos da lista anos:

1. dfp_bpa_all.csv;
2. dfp_bpp_all.csv;
3. itr_bpa_all.csv;
4. itr_bpp_all.csv.

segue um codigo que verifica se os arquivos existem:
me falta somente a concatenação.

```
listas = ['dfp','itr']
tipos = ['bpa','bpp']
anos = range(2010, 2021)
path_csv = 'C:/Users/Saulo/Desktop/projeto analise/download/arquivos/dfs/%s'
arq_csv = '/%s_%s_%d.csv'

concatenar = []

for lts in listas:
    for ano in anos:
        for tps in tipos:
            url = (path_csv % lts + arq_csv % (lts,tps,ano))
            #print(url)
            if os.path.isfile(url):
                concatenar.append(url)
print(concatenar)
```

Comment: Qual o conteúdo de `listas_tipos_anos.csv`?

Comment: conteúdo ja foi "trato", os arquivos separados são equiparados na estrutura, por isso de eu querer concatenar, somente um arquivo em csv distinguindo apenas listas_tipos

Comment: precisa ser em Python? é periódico? se não apenas copie `cp a.csv b.csv c.csv final.csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obrigado Paulo Marques, segue o código que resolveu meu problema, foi trabalhoso mas valeu a pena

```
# Concatenar
import pandas as pd
import glob

listas = ['dfp','itr']
tipos = ['bpa','bpp']

path = '"DIRETÓRIO"/%s/%s'
path1 = '"DIRETÓRIO"'

for lts in listas:
    for tps in tipos:
        csv = path % (lts,tps)
        all_files = glob.glob(csv + '/*.csv')
        li = []
        for files in all_files:
            df = pd.read_csv(files, sep=';', encoding='iso-8859-1')
            li.append(df)
        frame = pd.concat(li,axis=0,ignore_index=True)
        print(frame)
        frame.to_csv(path1 + '/%s_%s_all.csv'% (lts,tps), sep=';', encoding='iso-8859-1',index=False)
```

Comment: A utilização do pandas foi uma ótima solução. Depois veja a diferença do `concat` e do `merge`. Os dois métodos são realmente úteis!
Ao utilizar o Python 3, procure usar o `fstring`. Linhas como `csv = path % (lts,tps)` poderiam ser substituídas por `csv = f'"DIRETÓRIO"/{lts}/{tps}'`, outra coisa: use e abuse do `os.path.join`. Este método concatena diretórios com nomes de arquivos. No lugar de `path1 + '/%s_%s_all.csv'% (lts,tps)` poderia usar `os.path.join(path1, f"{lts}_{tps}_all.csv")`

Comment: obrigado pelas dicas, vou testar em breve

Answer (score 1):

Se vc realmente quiser fazê-lo com Python, seria algo como

```
txt = ''
for arquivo in contatenar:
    with open(arquivo, 'r') as f:
        txt += f.read()

with open("arquivo_final.csv", "w") as saida:
    saida.write(txt)
```

Espero que ajude.